# TRENDnet ac1900 tew-809ub chipset 20f4:809a -- has anyone got this working with Linux Mint 20?

Tags: wifi, drivers, usb

Has anyone got the TRENDnet ac1900 tew-809ub chipset 20f4:809a working with Mint 20?

```
kaos@kaos-HP-Laptop-17-ca0xxx:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 021: ID 20f4:809a TRENDnet 
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0408:5362 Quanta Computer, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0438:7900 Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. Root Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 015: ID 04a9:182b Canon, Inc. 
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 13fe:4300 Kingston Technology Company Inc. USB2.0 HUB
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 058f:6366 Alcor Micro Corp. Multi Flash Reader
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 214b:7250  USB2.0 HUB
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 1038:160e SteelSeries ApS USB2.0 HUB
Bus 002 Device 010: ID 046d:c52f Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 05e3:0608 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
kaos@kaos-HP-Laptop-17-ca0xxx:~$
```